# Crear sección Favoritos htmls Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando hacer como una especie de carro de compras pero con ejercicios, así que cuando vea un ejercicio que guste lo añada a Favoritos y quede en una página que se llame favoritos.

Es para una aplicación híbrida con Phonegap, pero no sé como hacerla, hice mi investigación y los favoritos que hay es añadir favoritos al navegador y eso no es lo que quiero.

Agradezco si alguien tiene más o menos una idea de como se podría hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un catálogo de cosas, las que sean, y necesitas poder guardarte un listado de selecciones: necesitas algún sistema para almacenar o persistir datos.

Si no tienes backend, con tecnologías front y sin frameworks, ni cosas así, puedes usar alguno de los sistemas disponibles para almacenar datos en el navegador, las más comunes son ***session storage*** y ***local storage***.

Comment: buena opción, aunque en este caso no iría con sessionStorage porque los datos se perderían al cerrar el navegador